# python script that runs inside a docker image, doesn't use the usual PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, docker, pip, amazon-sagemaker

I'm creating a docker image using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN apt-get update && pip install sagemaker boto3 numpy sagemaker-training

# Copies the training code inside the container
COPY cv.py /opt/ml/code/train.py
COPY scikit_learn_iris.py /opt/ml/code/scikit_learn_iris.py

# Defines train.py as script entrypoint
ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM train.py

# Install custom packages specified in requirements.txts
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONPATH "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages"
```

In the requirements file, I have added `lightgbm` library and it installs it successfully inside the docker image. When sagemaker runs starts to run `scikit_learn_iris.py` cause it can't import `lightgbm`: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lightgbm'`. I'm printing the sys path and PYTHONPATH at the start of `scikit_learn_iris.py` script and it shows the following results :

```
sys.path = ['/opt/ml/code', '/opt/ml/code', '/miniconda3/bin', '/miniconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/miniconda3/lib/python3.7', '/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

PYTHONPATH = ['/opt/ml/code', '/miniconda3/bin', '/miniconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/miniconda3/lib/python3.7', '/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

why the script is using `/miniconda3/...` to find the libraries? Even tough I'm setting `PYTHONPATH` env variable in the Dockerfile? How do I make it understand to look in the correct path?! This path `/miniconda3/` doesn't even exists in the docker image when I checked (using `docker run -it IMAGE_NAME bash`)

Comment: Have you tried setting PYTHONPATH ENV before installing `sagemaker-training` ? Is there a reason you need to set the PYTHONPATH ENV? Do you have any issues when you do not set it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any base image in the Dockerfile, it is possible that came from a base image if there was any. And I don't know if this helps, but this is the ```prinenv`` output from my training image. And I didn't have to set PYTHONPATH and it's working without issue.

```
SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY=/opt/ml/code
OLDPWD=/src
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
PATH=/opt/amazon/openmpi/nvidia/bin:/opt/amazon/openmpi/bin/:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
TA_PREFIX=/opt/ta-lib-core
SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM=main.py
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
KMP_AFFINITY=granularity=fine,compact,1,0
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/opt/amazon/openmpi/lib/:/opt/amazon/efa/lib/:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:/usr/local/lib
NV_CUDA_COMPAT_PACKAGE=cuda-compat-11-2
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
TF_AUTOTUNE_THRESHOLD=2
NVARCH=x86_64
SHLVL=1
PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
PYTHON=python3.9
DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
KMP_BLOCKTIME=1
TERM=xterm
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
TF_VERSION=2.10
KMP_SETTINGS=0
CUDA_VERSION=11.2.2
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
LANG=C.UTF-8
HOME=/root
NV_CUDA_CUDART_VERSION=11.2.152-1
NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=compute,utility
RDMAV_FORK_SAFE=1
PWD=/src/pybox2d
NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA=cuda>=11.2 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451
PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.10
HOSTNAME=8b1eccd1c2ad
PIP=pip3
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
```